# C, read from file into array, number by number

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

```
void readfromFile() {

    FILE *myFile;
    myFile = fopen("matrikel.txt", "r");

    //read file into array
    int numberArray[12];
    int i;

    if (myFile == NULL) {
        printf("Error Reading File\n");
        exit (0);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        fscanf(myFile, "%d,", &numberArray[i] );
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        printf("Number is: %d\n\n", numberArray[i]);
    }

    fclose(myFile);
}
```

"matrikel.txt" contains

```
808098822790
```

The number seems to be too long for the `int numberArray[12]`, when running the code it prints a random number.
When cutting some of the single integers from the end of the number it works, the maximum length seems to be 9.

I'm not quite sure but shouldn't the `fscanf` in the first for loop print one single digit number into each cell of `numberArray[]`?

Comment: You use the format `"%d,"` for reading the numbers, that expects each number to have a comma after it. Perhaps you want to read each *digit* separately instead? Then I suggest you read each digit as a character instead, and then convert that character to its corresponding `int` value instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay, sounds like what I was wanting to do, but how can I? I was told to use an array, can I read each digit as a char into an array?

Comment: Why not read each digit, as a character, into a `char` variable? Then convert it (by doing e.g. `char_variable - '0'`) and store that value in the `int` array you have?

Comment: I'm still not quite sure how to get it done, what I just tried didn't work. I will take a look at your idea when I have time, later today. Thanks for the idea :)

Comment: @user3121023 great, that just did it, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A format specifier for scanf follows this prototype: `%[*][width][length]specifier`
So, with `%1d` you will read a single number each time.
But would be more simple to read each number as a char with `fgetc(myFile);`

```
 for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
     int c = fgetc(myFile);
     if(c == EOF)
        break;
     numberArray[i] = c - '0';
 }
```

Comment: I will look into your post later, thanks for providing me with some answers